# Move template function to custom module

Tags: 7, theming

I have a function in my template.php file but I've now created a module that manages these particular tasks so I want to move the function over.

This is what I have in my template.php file:

```
function MYTHEME_menu_tree__main_menu($variables){
    return '<ul class="menu my-class">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

This works file but when I move it into my custom module (`mymodule.module` file) if doesn't work.

I've tried this:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_tree__main_menu($variables){
    return '<ul class="menu my-class">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';  
}
```

and this:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_menu_tree__main_menu($variables){
    return '<ul class="menu my-class">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';  
}
```

but not happening.

Can anyone see where i'm going wrong? or am I way off on this and it can't be done like this?

Comment: You would need to use `hook_theme_registry_alter()` and replace the callback function for that hook; the naming convention for overrides only works for themes

Comment: Thanks @Clive - I don't quite understand. Are you able to elaborate on your response.

Answer (score 0):

[`hook_theme_registry_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7.x) allows a module to step in to override registered theme callback functions. In your case, you're looking to override the `menu_tree__main_menu` entry and replace its callback function:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  if ($theme_registry['menu_tree__main_menu']) {
    // @TODO: override
    // $theme_registry['menu_tree__main_menu']['function']
    // $theme_registry['menu_tree__main_menu']['type']
    // $theme_registry['menu_tree__main_menu']['theme path']
    // for your new module theme function
  }
}
```

See the **Return Value** section of [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7.x) for more information on what a theme registry entry contains.